# Cypher: If node not exists, create multiple nodes and relations

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases, cql

I want to `MERGE` a node:

`MERGE (a: Article {URL: event.URL})`

If the node does not exist, I need to do this:

```
ON CREATE FOREACH( site_name in CASE WHEN event.site_name is not null then [1] ELSE [] END |
    MERGE (w: Website { value: event.site_name})
    MERGE (w)-[:PUBLISHED]->(a))

    // all of the tag creation
    FOREACH( tag in CASE WHEN event.tags is not NULL then event.tags else [] END |
    Merge (t: Article_Tag {value: tag})
    CREATE (a)-[: HAS_ARICLE_TAG {date:event_datetime}]->(t))
```

I believe that `ON CREATE` only works with `SET`, but as above, i need to execute multiple statements. Is there a way to create multiple nodes and relationships with an `ON CREATE` clause?

EDIT: I have tried `ON CREATE FOREACH(ignoreme in case when event.article is not null then [1] else [] end |... multiple statements` but this does not escape the SET problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is the best way to do this: just wrap it in a FOREACH statement

```
MATCH (a: Article {URL: event.URL})
FOREACH(ignoreme in case when a is not null then [1] else [] end |... Statement here...)
```